# Testing a KeyedDecodingContainer and UnkeyedDecodingContainer extension to work with a Decodable process

Tags: xctest, codable, decodable

Some time ago I created an extension for KeyedDecodingContainer and UnkeyedDecodingContainer in order to be able to decode a Dictionary<String, Any>. The implementation can be found here [Gist](https://gist.github.com/reimondhill/2ce9938cb8b546549b02abcf89bae400).

Now it's time to test it but I can't figure out how to create neither a KeyedDecodingContainer nor UnkeyedDecodingContainer.

I tried to start something but it feels I am in the wrong path...

```
let keyedDecodingContainer = KeyedDecodingContainer(MyKeyedDecodingContainer())
struct MyKeyedDecodingContainer: KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol {
    typealias Key = ...
    
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is about a XML decoder, but it discusses a custom KeyedDecodingContainer: https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E115-building-a-custom-xml-decoder